# How can I use find.select in MongoDB from Express.js?

Tags: mongodb, express

I want to fetch all the email IDs from a MongoDB collection in Express.js, so I'm using
db.collection("user").find({}).select({"email":1,"_id":0});
this command from Express.js, but in console it is showing "TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).select is not a function".

I have also used db.collection("user").find({},{"email":1,"_id":0}); this command from Express.js, but it returning all the existing fields, but I want only email IDs, but this same command is giving the desired out put from the MongoDB terminal.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize the `db` instance?

Comment: Did you try `project` instead of `select`? You can refer to the official document [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/project/)